# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I'm trying to run RSelenium using the rsDriver function, but when I run 
`rD <- rsDriver()`
I get a message telling me I need a newer version of Chrome:

```
> rD <- rsDriver()
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

The error message appears to say that I need Chrome version 74.0.3729.6, but when I look in Chrome's settings, it tells me that I'm running the latest stable version (73.0.3683.75). Upon further googling, 74.0.3729.6 is a pre-release dev version of Chrome: do I need to install this in order to use ChromeDriver with RSelenium?

I'm not wedded to the idea of using Chrome, but I haven't been able to get rsDriver to use Firefox: when I specify `browser = "firefox"`, rsDriver gives me the same error message about ChromeDriver not supporting my version of Chrome.

My session info is:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] wdman_0.2.4     forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.8     purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.2    
 [8] tibble_2.0.1    ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.2.0      RSelenium_1.7.5
```

Comment: Download this old version. Works fine! >>---> **https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.46/**

Comment: in my case, if error says it only supports version 76, i can't use chrome 76.xxx. if i downgrade to 75.xxx, it says it only supports version 75. If i try the latest version (78 currently), it works

Comment: @BingLi224 which version of selenium and Python are used? I hit the same issue though the version of Chrome is 78.0.3904.70

Comment: @zzxwill Selenium 3.141.0, Python 3.7.3, Chrome 78.0.3904.70 (currently, but not sure what it was at that moment)

Comment: If you have choco you can "choco update chromedriver"

Comment: The easiest way i found today is just check your chrome version and download  web - driver and copy that to c:/programfiles/python/.. and use this path to your script ...... really working for me.

Comment: This helped me install the lasted Google Chrome on Ubuntu via command line: https://askubuntu.com/a/510063/48214

Comment: Use this to update both Chromedriver and Chrome to latest on Ubuntu/Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61218681/4240654

Comment: I checked the version of my google chrome browser installed on my pc and then downloaded `ChromeDriver` suited to my browser version. You can download it from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I encountered the same issue today and found this post and others from Google. I think I may have a more direct solution as a modification of your code. The previous answer is correct in identifying the mismatch in versions.

I tried the proposed solutions to no avail. I found that the versions were correct on my computer. However, this mismatch error was not resulting from the actual versions installed on the computer, but rather the RSelenium code is seeking the "latest" version of Chrome/ChromeDriver by default argument. See `?rsDriver()` help page for the arguments.

If you run the code `binman::list_versions("chromedriver")` as specified in the help documentation, then you can identify the versions of compatible with the function. In my case, I was able to use the following code to establish a connection.

`driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="73.0.3683.68", extraCapabilities = eCaps)`

You should be able to specify your version of Chrome with the `chromever=` argument. I had to use the closest version, though (my chrome version was "73.0.3683.75").

Hope this helps!

Comment: CAD's answer worked for me with the caveat chrome://settings/help to view and/or update your Chrome browser version. In my case I clicked updated to update to Version: 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It seems that your variant is more suitable for my case. But I can not find how to say to protractor to use a version defined. Like this chromever="73.0.3683.68". In my case. I use lower version chromium-browser than protractor asks. This is my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984924/ng-e2e-can-not-start-because-of-the-chromedriver-74-0-3729-6?noredirect=1#comment98622261_55984924

Comment: Yo, sir,rock.  I modifed this code slightly to always use the latest version with:
`available.versions<-binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
latest.version = available.versions$win32[length(available.versions)]
`

Thanks for this!

Comment: Run the code `binman::list_versions("chromedriver")` where? As specified in *what* documentation?

Comment: I use: rsDriver(chromever = binman::list_versions("chromedriver")$win32[4])

Answer (score 88):

For MacOS chromedriver upgrade did the trick:

```
brew upgrade --cask chromedriver
```

Comment: Nice, this got me on the right track except I was using `chromedriver-beta`, which was expecting a later version of Chrome. So what I did: `brew cask uninstall chromedriver-beta; brew cask install chromedriver`

Comment: This only works if you installed chromedriver via brew. I had installed it via a direct download, so first ran `rm /usr/local/bin/chromedriver` and then `brew cask install chromedriver` to get the latest version.

In any case, upgrading chromedriver was the solution.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer instead of the one suggesting to downgrade chrome

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Comment: As of 2021, if you get the error `Error: Unknown command: cask`, you need instead to run the command: `brew reinstall chromedriver`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413621/homebrew-cask-option-not-recognized for more info. Fyi, the new cask install syntax is: `brew install --cask chromedriver`

Answer (score 74):

This error message...

```
Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.3 x86_64)
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* expects the *Chrome Browser* version to be **74**.

---

### [Quick installation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#quick-installation) of the latest ChromeDriver

To install the latest version of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091121/why-doesnt-chromedriver-require-chrome-or-chromium/51096327#51096327) you can use:

- **Mac users with Homebrew**: `brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver`
- **Debian based Linux distros**: `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`
- **Windows users with Chocolatey installed**: `choco install chromedriver`

---

### Analysis

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=74.0.3729.6*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=74.0.3729.6*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v74**

- You are using the currently released *chrome=73.0*

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6* and the *Chrome Browser v73.0*

---

### Solution

- Downgrade *ChromeDriver* to [ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at *Chrome v73* level. ([as per ChromeDriver v73.0.3683.68 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/73.0.3683.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to work with a specific version of ChromeDriver while Chrome Browser gets updated automatically through Python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692358/how-to-work-with-a-specific-version-of-chromedriver-while-chrome-browser-gets-up/50697221#50697221)

Comment: I've downgraded ChromeDriver to v73.0.3683.68, cleaned the project workspace, and rebuilt it with only the required dependencies. It now gives me a different error message when I run `rD <- rsDriver()`, ending in:

`[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Could not open chrome browser.

Client error message:

Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: 

Connection refused

Check server log for further details.

Warning message:

In rsDriver() : Could not determine server status.`

Comment: Also apologies if this is obvious (this is my first time trying to do anything like this), but what is the Web Client and what is a GA? Additionally, what is the @Test and can I run this within RStudio?

Comment: _Web Client_ -> _Chrome Browser_, _GA_ -> _General Avaiibility_ , _@Test_ -> An annotation used to identify a _test_ using _JUnit_ / _TestNG_ (you can simply consider as _test_)

Comment: This is just a generic answer about how to troubleshoot version mismatches when using `Selenium`. This answer doesn't refer to `R` or `RSelenium` at all. This accepted answer should be the one by @CAD below.

Comment: For updating Chromedriver on Ubuntu, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649230/how-to-update-chromedriver-on-ubuntu

Comment: Make sure you check what version your Chrome browser is, then go the Chrome Driver page to download the compatible driver for your browser version https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: +1 for the explanation (teach a man to fish and all that). I upgraded my chromedriver to match my chrome version (Chrome Help -> About - version) and it was fixed.

Comment: Just to sync up, the first command for mac can be replaced with `brew tap homebrew/cask && brew install --cask chromedriver`

Answer (score 33):

Updating the **Google Chrome** version to **74** worked for me.

**Steps:**
1. Go to Help -> About Google Chrome -> Chrome will automatically look for updates(update Chrome to the latest version)

[image]

Answer (score 23):

I had to reinstall protractor for it to pull the updated `webdriver-manager` module. Also, per @Mark’s comment, the `package-lock.json` may be locking the dependency.

```
npm uninstall protractor
npm install --save-dev protractor
```

Then, make sure to check the `maxChromedriver` value in `node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/config.json` after re-install to verify it matches the desired Chrome driver version.

Answer (score 15):

### Update

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/pull/237) to RSelenium adding the ChromeDriver version selection logic proposed in my original answer. Until it gets merged (if at all), you can install it with

```r
remotes::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium#237")
```

Then you can call `rsDriver()` with the new `chromever = "latest_compatible"` option which should always select the right ChromeDriver version:

```r
RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                    chromever = "latest_compatible")
```

### Original answer

I ran into the same kind of error using `RSelenium::rsDriver()`'s default `chromever = "latest"` setting which resulted in the failed attempt to combine `chromedriver 75.0.3770.8` with latest `google-chrome-stable 74.0.3729.157`:

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
```

Since this obviously seems to be a recurring and pretty annoying issue, I have come up with the following **workaround to always use the latest compatible ChromeDriver version**:

```r
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                          chromever =
                                  system2(command = "google-chrome-stable",
                                          args = "--version",
                                          stdout = TRUE,
                                          stderr = TRUE) %>%
                                  stringr::str_extract(pattern = "(?<=Chrome )\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.") %>%
                                  magrittr::extract(!is.na(.)) %>%
                                  stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\.",
                                                           replacement = "\\\\.") %>%
                                  paste0("^",  .) %>%
                                  stringr::str_subset(string =
                                                              binman::list_versions(appname = "chromedriver") %>%
                                                              dplyr::last()) %>%
                                  as.numeric_version() %>%
                                  max() %>%
                                  as.character())
```

The above code is **only tested under Linux** and makes use of some [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) packages (install them beforehand or rewrite it in base R). For other operating systems you might have to adapt it a bit, particularly replace `command = "google-chrome-stable"` with the system-specific command to launch Google Chrome:

- On [macOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1144651/get-chrome-version-from-commandline-in-mac) it should be enough to replace `command = "google-chrome-stable"` with `command = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"`.
- On Windows a [plattform-specific bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158372) prevents us from calling the Google Chrome binary directly to get its version number. Instead do the following:

  ```r
  rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                            chromever =
                              system2(command = "wmic",
                                      args = 'datafile where name="C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
                                      stdout = TRUE,
                                      stderr = TRUE) %>%
                              stringr::str_extract(pattern = "(?<=Version=)\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.") %>%
                              magrittr::extract(!is.na(.)) %>%
                              stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\.",
                                                       replacement = "\\\\.") %>%
                              paste0("^",  .) %>%
                              stringr::str_subset(string =
                                                          binman::list_versions(appname = "chromedriver") %>%
                                                          dplyr::last()) %>% 
                              as.numeric_version() %>%
                              max() %>%
                              as.character())
  ```

Basically, the code just ensures the latest ChromeDriver version *matching the major-minor-patch version number of the system's stable Google Chrome browser* is passed as `chromever` argument. This procedure should adhere to the [official ChromeDriver versioning scheme](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection). Quote:

> - ChromeDriver uses the same version number scheme as Chrome (...)
> - Each version of ChromeDriver supports Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20 supports all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683.

Comment: The hero we need. Thanks! P.S: I edited to include the Windows code to make it easier for future readers

Comment:  I've just integrated it properly since you've succesfully tested it!

Answer (score 9):

I dealed with this issue today and upgrading my webdrivermanger solved it for me (My previous version was 3.0.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've resolved the same issue by upgrading to 3.3.0 version,Thank you

Comment: I was on version 1.x. Updating to 3.3.0 fixed it for me as well.

Comment: You have to use the latest version which is <version>3.6.2</version>.

Comment: I think this answer would be vastly improved by including steps on how one might go about upgrading their "webdrivermanager."  All you've done here is provided some XML without much in the way of explanation.  Would you mind updating this answer with some additional details?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Travis CI alternative

*Another answer since Francesco Borzi's didn't work for me.*

Add this to your travis.yml:

```
addons:
  chrome: stable

before_script:
  - LATEST_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -s "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"`
  - curl "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${LATEST_CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}/chromedriver_linux64.zip" -O
  - unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/bin
```

Many thanks and credit to tagliala on github:

https://github.com/diowa/ruby2-rails5-bootstrap-heroku/commit/6ba95f33f922895090d3fabc140816db67b09672

Answer (score 3):

I was really struggling with this mismatch between ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6 and the Chrome Browser v73.0. I finally found a way to get ChromeDriver to an earlier version,

1. In Chrome > About Google Chrome, copy the the version number, except for the last group. For instance, 72.0.3626.
2. Paste that version at the end of this url and visit it. It will come back with a version, which you should copy.
   https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_
3. Back in the command line, run `bundle exec chromedriver-update <copied version>`

Comment: I fount the solution, and taught - there must be an answer like this already :)

Answer (score 3):

### Travis CI

I had the same issue in Travis and solved by adding:

```
addons:
  chrome: stable
```

to my `.travis.yml` file.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577404/2441263

Answer (score 3):

```
$ which chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105
```

I downloaded a zip file from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
It says "If you are using Chrome version 79, please download ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36"
and I was using Chrome version 79. (I checked `chrome://settings/help`) Apparently, the error for me was "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 78"

And then I clicked the zip file and move that "chromedriver" file into `/usr/local/bin/` directory. That solved the issue.

```
$ which chromedriver
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me

1. Make sure you're using R 3.5.3 or greater
2. `driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"), chromever="73.0.3683.68")`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this issue and was able to solve by 2 main steps:

## 1 - Update to latest chromedriver via homebrew cli

```
brew cask upgrade chromedriver
```

## 2 - update to lastest ver via Chrome GUI

chrome://settings/help or `cmd` + `,` then tacking on help at the end (your choice)

from there you should land on the About Chrome Page.  Here you will need to verify that you are on the latest and greatest version (problem i was running into stemmed from a mismatch in the cli vs the current chrome version)

if you getting the error, you will see a `update & relaunch` primary action button.

after chrome "relaunches" it will now have the newest version matching your cli

example:

```
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I am using robot framework (Selenium based framework) in a **Docker** instance. The reason was docker was using cached `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` for Chrome but it has installed latest chrome driver which was a later version.

Then I used below command and error resolved.

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error:

> session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75
>
> ...
>
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

We are running the tests from a computer that has no real UI, so I had to work via a command line (CLI).

I started by detecting the current version of Chrome that was installed on the Linux computer:

```
$> google-chrome --version
```

And got this response:

> Google Chrome 74.0.3729.169

So then I updated the Chrome version like that:

```
$> sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

And after checking again the version I got this:

> Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100

Then the Selenium tests were able to run smoothly.

Comment: This is applicable when the chrome browser was installed via repo/ppa and cannot update itself

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to downgrade Chrome anymore, when you get this error only means it's time to run `webdriver-manager update` again

Answer (score 1):

Just update protractor:

```
npm install protractor@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the exact version of your Chrome installation like this:

`webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 73.0.3683.75`

Maybe you need to do a `webdriver-manager clean` first in the case of a downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by simply downloading a `chromedriver` file for a previous version of chrome. I have found that version 79 of Chrome is compatible with the current version of Selenium.

I then saved it in a specified path, and linked that path to my `webdriver`.

The exact steps are specified in this link:
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problems like this, the problems is come inside the pipeline when running my selenium test that need chromedriver package to running the e2e test.

[My error build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPyNE.png)

The problems is just because in the pipeline (in my case) is having the chrome version 73, and my chromedriver package is installed on version 74.

> Finally there are two simple solutions:
>
> 1. Downgrade your chrome
> 2. Downgrade your chromedriver package version. in my case, cause i running inside the pipeline i need to install chromedriver before
>      running the selenium test like displayed below.
>
>    `- script: npm install chromedriver@73.0.0 --chromedriver-force-download
>      displayName: 'Install Chrome'`

Comment: I am having a same problem, How to know the chrome -version on the Jenkins node?

Comment: How to install a chrome on the node as a part of build pipeline if there is no chrome

Comment: to install a chrome as a part of build pipeline you can just add the task script i've put above.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me today.

My solution:

Download the latest stable release of chromedriver: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Update the chrome driver on your Selenium folder. This is a bit hard, because is in a hidden folder on your PC called AppData. Here is how I did it in my computer (Windows 7):

C: > users > your user > \AppData (you need to write this in the folder path box, since it is a hidden folder) > Local (this is the folder name in portuguese, maybe it will have a different name for you) > SeleniumBasic

There you will find the chromedriver application. Just rename it (in case it does not work, you want to have the older version) and than paste the newest release.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue recently. This was my error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76 (SessionNotCreated)
```

This fix worked for me:

- make sure there are no running chromedriver.exe processes (if needed kill them all e.g. via task manager)
- go to bin folder and delete chromedriver.exe file from there (in my case it was: `[project_folder]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You have the latest version of webdriver-manager. You can install the same using `npm i webdriver-manager@latest --save`

Then run the following

```
command.webdriver-manager update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on my mac os bigsur
In 2021, on mac the correct command is

```
brew upgrade --cask chromedriver
```