# ng e2e can not start because of the chromedriver_74.0.3729.6

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

I run

```
ng e2e
```

I receive the error log.

```
Date: 2019-05-04T16:49:58.382Z
Hash: 1e913b86ba4c68be859d
Time: 7496ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 284 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 12.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 181 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.1 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
[19:49:58] I/update - chromedriver: file exists /home/martin/tmp/appS/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.zip
[19:49:58] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_74.0.3729.6.zip
[19:49:58] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/martin/tmp/appS/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_74.0.3729.6
[19:49:58] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_74.0.3729.6 up to date
[19:49:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:49:59] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[19:49:59] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64
```

...

```
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I see that the problem is with the driver. I saw similar posts. I tried to install the plugin required.

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=74.0.3729.6
```

I have:

```
webdriver-manager status
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.1.4
[19:49:26] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.141.59 [last]
[19:49:26] I/status - chromedriver version available: 74.0.3729.6 [last]
[19:49:26] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.24.0 [last]
[19:49:26] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[19:49:26] I/status - appium is not present
```

I have restarted the selenium server. I see the required driver is used.

```
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.1.4
[19:49:33] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/home/martin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_74.0.3729.6 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/home/martin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0 -jar /home/martin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -port 4444
```

The same error occurs. I guess I need to use a lower version. What are your suggestions?
Regards.

Comment: Check your chrome version, the browser version should be 74 if you are using chromedriver 74.0.3729.6.

Comment: I have two way: update the browser to the latest or down the web-driver. webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=73.0.3683.86 and starated the same way. But I can not make protractor to use the current version. It always asks for the latest.

Comment: My problem was trivial, I used chromium-browser. I installed chrome and all problems were resolved. It could work with chromium but with extra actions.