# Is this error due to the wrong version of chromdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I' m trying to access websites through python, but after 3 lines of coding, I' m stuck. One of the error messages says :

> *selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
>   version 77* "

Maybe it's because I have the wrong version of ChromeDriver? If so what should I do?

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\kyg\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure Chrome 77 is installed

Comment: Which version of chrome is installed on your computer? You should download the supported version of chrome driver [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Please check that your Chromedriver & Chrome Browser version is the same.

Step 2: Go to Windows/System32 and make sure there is no chromedriver file is there.

Step 3: If you find a chrome driver in System32 delete it or replace it with the latest one.

Answer (score -1):

I was actually keeping on browsing and found an answer for my question. If anyone else is having the same problem, go to 
[session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7) 
and the read the answer for this question!!