# R RSelenium rsDriver chrome browser error on Mac

Tags: r, macos, rselenium

I am using a Mac (OS 10.13.6) and am trying to learn how to use RSelenium.

I have installed RSelenium but am having trouble with the rsDriver command:

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome",chromever="80.0.3987.106")
```

I get this error:

```
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "80.0.3987.106") :
Could not determine server status.
```

I've been poking around for help for a couple of days now but am not clear on the appropriate solution here. I've tried the command with `chromever="latest"` and following the suggested workaround found here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7/56173984#56173984). Furthermore, I don't know where to find the "server log" mentioned in the error.

Having never used this package before, or done this type of thing, I can't tell if I just don't have things set up on my machine correctly (non-R requirements of RSelenium that I need to install and where), or whether this is strictly a chrome browser setting/verison issue, or generally mac compatibility issue.

Does anyone an updated (i.e. not involving the defunct `checkForServer()` command) set of steps (for absolute Selenium beginners) for getting RSelenium set up and rsDriver working on a mac?

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of trials and errors, I managed to solve the same issue by installing 
[Java SE Development Kit 14](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) on my Mac.

I hope this solves your issue.