# Selenium Issue: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81 using Selenium and Google Chrome 84.0

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to scrape some data off the web however all my attempts have failed so far. Below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "/Applications/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
```

The error I keep getting is below:

> SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

I've updated Selenium and my ChromeDriver file. I am currently using Chrome v84 as my browser. Also, I am on a Mac

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74 error with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v81.0* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=81.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=81.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/81.0.4044.138/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 81**

- You are using the latest *chrome=84.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v84.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 84**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v81.0* and the *Chrome Browser v84.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.

Comment: If you read the whole question description you'd know the asker has already updated ChromeDriver, and that this solution of yours doesn't actually solve anything here.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome browser is updating time to time so you need to you exact chrome driver version accourding to your browser version .plese check your browser version by going to "About chrome"
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads in here you can download chrome driver versions