# How do I fix this error in selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium pyhthon to try and open amazon.com in google chrome, but I keep getting this error message when I run the code.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

I have tried to search up this error on stackoverflow, but all I can find is [Selenium gives "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026987/selenium-gives-selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown), which I cannot understand. I am using mac M1 and I have the chrome version 92.0.4515.107. My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = "/Users/asznee/selenium/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
```

Comment: Where is your Google Chrome installed , in which directory ?

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459351/chrome-driver-selenium/64460007#64460007 please check the location of your chromedriver

Comment: My google chrome is /User/asznee/Desktop/Downloads/Google Chrome

Comment: And my chrome driver is in /User/asznee/selenium/chromedriver

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /User/asznee/Desktop/Downloads/Google Chrome. This is the error once I put 'options.binary_location = "/User/asznee/Desktop/Downloads/Google Chrome"' as the chrome_options

Answer (score 0):

See your Google chrome is not installed in default location which is

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
```

it is installed :

```
C:\Users\asznee\Desktop\Downloads\Google Chrome\Application
```

right  ?

so for solving this issue, your chromdriver.exe needs to know where Google chrome is installed :-

You can try the below code :-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/Users/asznee/Desktop/Downloads/Google Chrome/Application/chrome"
chrome_driver_binary = "/Users/asznee/selenium/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options = options)
```

Comment: It just gives this error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at /Users/asznee/Desktop/Downloads/Google Chrome/Application/chrome

Comment: I am using windows so I have that application folder, Do you happen to have the same structure ?  You can change it that to the location of your Google chrome installed directory and try again

Comment: My structure is just /Users/asznee/Desktop/Downloads

Comment: Do you see Chrome launcher in Downloads ? Are you sure if there isn't folder ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to specify the path of the chrome driver just keep the chrome driver in the project
just copy and paste in the project

and start initializing the web driver
simply start typing with
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
and enter the URL of the application
and follow the code

Comment: What is the chrome driver?

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

WebDriver is having unimplemented methods

here is chrome driver is implementing these unimplemented methods

chrome driver is just the driver which you're telling the selenium to run the test on the chrome browser.
you can download it on the

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

if you want to work with the firefox browser you use the gecko driver.