# Can no longer run RSelenium Chrome Driver

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I'll start by saying I have ran into this issue many times in the past, and all that's been required is updating my Google Chrome version and then updating the `chromever =` param in `rsDriver()`. These are no longer working for me.

I've tried the solutions in many posts [(this one in particular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201226/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-7) but I still can't get it to work.

Here are some details:

- Computer/browser/R info:

  - Chrome Version: 89.0.4389.90
  - Mac Version: 10.15.4
  - RStudio Version: 1.3.959
- For the longest time, I've been able to use `chromever = "87.0.4280.20"` even though my browser wasn't on that version. I could open up a remote driver with `remDrall <- rsDriver(port = 4445L, browser = "chrome", chromever = "87.0.4280.20")`
- When I try this now, I get an error saying

  ```
  Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
  Current browser version is 89.0.4389.90 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
  ```
- This prompted me to try updating my ChromeDriver if it was stuck on 87. I updated it by manually downloading and moving to `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` as well as updating via `brew upgrade chromedriver`. As far as I know it worked, testing via:

  - `ls /usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/` gives me `89.0.4389.23`
  - `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` starts a chromedriver session with 89.0.4389.23
- I've tried using `chromever = "89.0.4389.23"` but I get an unknown server-side error. I know my chrome version is 89.0.4389.90, but that version isn't available to use in `rsDriver`.

I'm really not sure where to go from here. I just don't get why it says my ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 when I clearly have it updated to 89. Could it be that my `rsDriver` function is still picking up some old version of ChromeDriver? Can I direct it specifically to the one in `/usr/local/bin/`?

Any thoughts on what I can try next?

Comment: Seems like a better question for the package authors: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the suggestion. Sounds like other people are having similar issues, and the only solution is to TimeMachine a previous version of Chrome which is very unfortunate. Might just have to wait until it gets resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the chromedriver.exe file on you local directory with the updated version from here:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=89.0.4389.23/

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, and it drove me crazy!

I tried to figure out where Rselenium or Binman found the old versions of chromedriver.
`binman::appdir('chromeriver)` shows the chromedriver Rselenium uses is the path `~/Library/Application Support/binman_chromedriver`. Then I manually copied the compatible version of chromedriver there. Finally, I got a different error:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
Check server log for further details.
```

The error was solved by setting `chromever=NULL` in `rsDriver()` according to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735571/8822626). I finally got it to work!

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem last week and was able to get the command working again by making the following change to the `chromever` option:

Previous version that has stopped working:

```
rsDriver(chromever = "87.0.4280.88", browser = "chrome", extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```

New version that works:

```
rsDriver(chromever = "89.0.4389.23", browser = "chrome", extraCapabilities = eCaps)
```