# Set dpi with plotly

Tags: python, plotly-python

I know that savefig has an option dpi. but if I make plots with plotly and write image I don't have an option to set dpi.

How can I set dpi with plotly?

```
TypeError: write_image() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dpi'
```

Comment: [How can I save plotly graphs in high quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355444/how-can-i-save-plotly-graphs-in-high-quality)I also researched, but 'plotly' did not have the ability to adjust the `dpi`. I hope you find this answer helpful.

Answer (score 12):

There is an option of passing *scale* argument to *write_image* method, which helps in increasing the resolution (by putting the value greater than 1) -- the same purpose intended by *dpi*.

So, the code would be like:

`fig.write_image('figure.png', scale=2)`

Here, the scale is put *2*.

If the scale is less than *1*, that would decrease the dimension instead.

Answer (score 2):

As [Suraj Regmi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492052/12993040) already wrote, use the `scale` parameter:

In doing so, you will not violate the sizes of fonts and lines.
To understand what parameter you need keep in mind that with `scale` = 1 the image will be `700x500` pixels in size.

Thus, if you want an 130 mm image with a 300 dpi resolution, then

```
scale = (width_in_mm / 25.4) / (width_default_px / dpi) = (130 / 25.4) / (700 / 300) = 2.1934758155230596
```

or

```
scale = width_in_mm * 17780.0 # dpi=300
```